# Changing plotlys hovertip text color

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-python

I am running the code snippet displaying qualitative swatches from the [documentation on discrete colors](https://plotly.com/python/discrete-color/).

```
import plotly.express as px

fig = px.colors.qualitative.swatches()
fig.show()
```

How to I change the hovertip text to white?
I find some of the backgrounds dont have good contrast with the text.

[image: example]

Answer (score 3):

You can either change the text color or you can change the background color of the hover text. The way to do this can be found [here](https://plotly.com/python/hover-text-and-formatting/#customizing-hover-label-appearance) (plolty documentation for formatting hover text).

For changing the color of the font, you can add this line of code to your current code:

```
fig.update_layout(
hoverlabel=dict(
    font_color="white",
))
```

This gives a result that looks like this:

[image]

For changing the background color of the hover text, you can simply add this line to your code:

```
fig.update_layout(
    hoverlabel=dict(
        bgcolor="white",
    ))
```

This gives a result that looks like this:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

To retain hover background, **and** ability to read all entries - *e.g. you won't struggle to read white text on pastel swatches.*

```
#! /usr/bin/python3
##  pip3 install numpy pandas plotly
import plotly.express as px

fig = px .colors .qualitative .swatches()

for item in fig['data']:
    ##  print( type(item), '\n', item, '\n' )

    font_colors = []
    for data_entry in range(  len( item['customdata'] )  ):
        colorstring = item['marker']['color'][data_entry]

        if colorstring .startswith('#'):
            ##  print( colorstring )  ##  #336699
            rr = int( colorstring[1:3], 16 )  ##  0x33
            gg = int( colorstring[3:5], 16 )  ##  0x66
            bb = int( colorstring[5:], 16 )  ##  0x99
        else:
            ##  print( colorstring[4:-1] )  ##  rgb(33, 66, 99)
            rrggbb = colorstring[4:-1] .replace(' ', '' ) .split(',')

            rr = int( rrggbb[0] )  ##  33
            gg = int( rrggbb[1] )  ##  66
            bb = int( rrggbb[2] )  ##  99

        ##  stackoverflow.com/questions/596216/formula-to-determine-perceived-brightness-of-rgb-color
        if rr+rr+rr +gg+gg+gg+gg +bb > 255 *3:  ##  increase contrast
            rr, gg, bb = 0, 0, 0
        else:
            rr, gg, bb = 255, 255, 255

        hovercolor = f"rgb( {rr}, {gg}, {bb} )"
        font_colors .append( hovercolor )

    item['hoverlabel'] = dict( font_color=font_colors )

fig.show()
```

https://plotly.com/python/hover-text-and-formatting/
https://plotly.com/python/creating-and-updating-figures/